# Heroku won't scale dyno even tho it says it did

Tags: heroku

When I run `heroku ps:scale web=1`
It tell me `Scaling dynos... done, now running web at 1:Basic`
But then when I run `heroku ps`
I get `No dynos on ...`

As a result my app isn't running, I get these logs `heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET`

This happens after successfully deploying a build that upgrades my stack from 18 to 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After opening a ticket on Heroku, here is the solution from them:

Thanks for reaching out to us. Due to some issue in heroku-cli ps:scale command is not working properly on heroku-cli (we have informed it to engineering team) Please go to https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/APP_NAME/resources page and :-

click on Pencil icon near Dyno information and slide down to 0 then confirm.
click on Pencil icon near Dyno information and slide up to 1 then confirm.
Run: `heroku ps -a APP_NAME` on cli and check whether it worked or not.

*On my side there was no slider but a toggle button to toggle the dynos on and off.*